# Accessing a non-aliased table name relative to the graph node in DBT

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I have a macro that gets me the literal table name of a dbt model. If I am wanting to get the table name of every dbt model in a project I can generally run this macro:

```py
{% set table_names = [] %}

{% for node in graphs.nodes.values() | selectattr("resource_type", "equalto", "model") %}
  {{ table_names.append(node.config.alias) }}
{% endfor %}
```

But in the event that a model's config doesn't have an alias, the above code will append a `None` to the list. To solve for this problem we can add an if statement within the `for` loop like:

```py
  {% if node.config.alias %}
    {{ table_names.append(node.config.alias) }}
  {% else %}
    {% set alias = node.unique_id %}
    {{ table_names.append(alias.split('.')[-1]) }}
  {% endif %}
```

So my ultimate: Is there a way to get the name of a non aliased model in dbt without having to do the else statement in the above?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% positive on this, but try `node.alias` instead of `node.config.alias`.
Looks as if the manifest file puts either the alias or the model name there, depending on which one is being used to create the table/view name.